# Integrate ios keyboard extension with native keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, ios-extensions

I am creating a keyboard extension for ios

I just want an scroll strip at the upper part of the keyboard which would be some say some emojis.

But i want the native keyboard functioning as usual , jut a view on top of keboardview.

Do i need to implement the whole native keyboard ?

What the easy way to achieve this.

Please guide

Thank you

Comment: if you want to anything change in native keyboard like background. key position you must implement keyboard extension.

Comment: No change in native , i want a scrollview over keyboard which contains emojis , so user can select them when they want

Comment: I am familiar with extension , but i am afraid if i have to implement the whole keyboard in extension

Comment: then do like facebook did

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inputAccessoryView`

Please refer

[image]

Comment: i want a custom keyboard which would not be specific to an app , it  would show a horizontal bar above the keyboard , for that i have also created an extension.

Answer (score 0):

What you want simply can't be done in the current version of iOS (9.2). If you want to add functionality to the keyboard on a systemwide basis, you have to implement it all yourself, including the keyboard.